# Condition to insert data in database

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, combobox

Here is my scenerio.

```
 I have a combo box which has 8 items. {items : a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}
```

I have a table with column  Employee.

```
if  i select a and when i insert that into my database table,it should be 1
if  i select b and when i insert that into my database table,it should be 1  and so on for 8 items.
```

What i am trying is :

```
objSQLParms(12) = New SqlParameter("@Employee_Type", SqlDbType.SmallInt)
       If cmbList.Text.Trim = "Employee" Then
            If cmbemployee.Text.Trim.Length = 0 Then
                objSQLParms(12).Value = 0
            Else
                objSQLParms(12).Value = cmbemployee.Text.Trim.Substring(0, 1)
            End If
        Else
            objSQLParms(12).Value = 0
```

By doing this i am getting only value that is present in combo box.
How to write a cases in this scenerio to get numbers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you try like this ?

```
If cmbemployee.Text.Trim.Length = 0 Then
     objSQLParms(12).Value = 0
Else
     objSQLParms(12).Value = val(cmbemployee.Text.Trim.Substring(0, 1))
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

because when you fire event of button to insert in to database
the page is post back
and combobox value set to default "a"

you can solve it by put combobox in update panel
to avoid the reload of page